# infinite ajax scroll not loading javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

SO basically I am using this plugin

https://github.com/webcreate/Infinite-Ajax-Scroll

It fits my needs perfectly and is working pretty seamless.

My website is articles, the problem is the javascript only appears for the first page of data.

For example, my facebook like buttons, hover effect, etc etc only works for the original rows loaded, not for the rows loaded by the plugin when you scroll to load more.

Anyone experience this issue and know how to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: Yes, there is one error 
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/page/2
I do not think it is related though

Comment: Please post your relevant code.

Comment: Well I don't know. Errors can have a cascade affect.

Comment: the original url format is http://mysite.com/?page=2 , plugin rewrite to http://mysite.com/#/page/1

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.1.5 of IAS there is a new option called `onRenderComplete`, this is a callback function you can use to reinitialize other javascript code after new items have been added to the DOM.

You can read more about here: https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll#onrendercomplete

Basically you can put any code that lives in `$(document).ready()` into this callback.